# Commutative Ring with Identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How can I show that $(\mathbb Q,\oplus,\cdot)$ is a commutative ring with identity where $\oplus$ and $\cdot$ are defined as, $a\oplus b=a+b-1$ and $a\cdot b=a+b$?

According to the book, an algebraic structure $(R,\oplus,\cdot)$ is called a ring if the following conditions are satisfied:

1. $(R,\oplus)$ is an abelian group.
2. Associativity of multiplication holds: $a\cdot(b\cdot c) = (a\cdot b)\cdot c$.
3. The left distributive law $a\cdot(b\oplus c)=(a\cdot b)\oplus(a\cdot c)$ and the right distributive law $(b\oplus c)\cdot a=(b\cdot a)\oplus(c\cdot a)$ are satisfied by "$\oplus$" and "$\cdot$".

Though I was somehow able to prove first 2 conditions, the third condition is not getting satisfied. It's an "show that..." question, so the statement is definitely true. Can someone help me?

Comment: What do you need to show for something to be a ring and commutative? Moreover, what are $I$ and $+$ in this case?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: All I know that 1.it should be abelian group 2.it should follow associative and commutative law 3.it should follow left,right distributive law.Though I was able to prove first two conditions ,I am not able to figure out the 3rd condition.

Comment: Can you please show your computations for distributivity?

Comment: for instance yes - you want to expand both sides and rearrange terms such that you get equality

Comment: I seem to get  $a.(b⊕c) = a.(b+c-1) = a+b+c-1$ while $(a.b)⊕(a.c)= (a+b)⊕(a+c)=a+b+a+c-1$ and these seem to differ by $a$

Comment: I changed the symbol $Z$ to $\mathbb Q$. While the set of rational numbers was denoted by $Z$ in some old textbooks, the standard notation nowadays is $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @Stockfish For left distributive law condition is a.(b+c) = a.b + a.c so in this case a.(b⊕c) gives LHS as a.(b + c - 1) which reduces to a + b + c - 1 (. Condition as given is question).Now while solving RHS (a.b + a.c) after replacing the signs we get a.b ⊕ a.c -> (a+b)⊕(a+c)-> 2a + b + c -1.Hence LHS is not equal to RHS.Hence Left distributive law is not getting satisfied

Answer (score 2):

It is obviously not a ring. In what follows, $0$ and $1$ refer to the neutral elements of the *original* ring addition and multiplication, respectively.

Just note that $1$ is the neutral element for $\oplus$, and so it should satisfy $a\cdot 1=1$ for all $a\in R$, if $R$ is to be a ring. (This is because we know the additive identity is multiplicatively absorbing in a ring.)

But it does not: $a\cdot 1:=a+1\neq 1$, for any $a\neq 0$.

---

In case you have radically mistyped your problem, I would encourage you to search for duplicates before asking.  [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1042856/29335) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/538115/29335) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/506236/29335) are all similar, and may explain the answer to you faster than re-asking.